# Pushed unupdated branch to master, how is that possible?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Earlier this week I did some work, committed to my local master and pushed to remote master (on Bitbucket). Later my colleague worked on the same file, without doing a git pull first. He then committed and pushed his code to master, and now the head of our remote master contains his code changes, but not mine anymore. How is that possible? I know pushing to master is frowned upon but still, should his push not be rejected? Or maybe he did a forced push? He uses Phpstorm  to do his git commands, maybe this is a phpstorm thing?

Mark

Comment: You might want to [prevent changes to master without a pull request](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html).

Comment: Do not be alarmed!  Your commits are (almost certainly) still in the remote repo and can be recovered.  In the default settings (for git, not bitbucket) you should have 30 days before the commits are pruned.  You'll just need to merge them back into the main branch.

Comment: Side note, this is one example of why you very rarely want to use `git push --force`. Had your colleague used `git push --force-with-lease` instead, he would have gotten an error telling him to fetch first, and then he would have seen your changes and then he could have rebased onto your changes (or merged into) before pushing. And also, like @GG said, you should consider requiring a PR into master.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Unfortunately, servers are usually configured *without* the 30-day grace period. Fortunately, some servers are configured *with* the 30-day grace period. I'm not sure if this continues with an "unfortunately" about Bitbucket, but then there's a "fortunately" about your own *local* Git repository. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is that possible?

It is possible that they used a forced push.

> I know pushing to master is frowned upon but still, should his push
> not be rejected?

It depends on how the repo is configured.  I don't know how BitBucket manages this but as an example, GitHub supports disabling forced pushes.

> Or maybe he did a forced push?

Likely.

> He uses Phpstorm to do his git commands, maybe this is a phpstorm
> thing?

Nothing in the description sounds like a Phpstorm thing.

Comment: This is almost definitely a force push. Whilst the best option is to discourage or prevent force pushes altogether, a protip for your colleague: instead of using `--force`, use `--force-with-lease`, as this achieves the same thing (forcing an overwrite of the remote branch with the state of your local branch) but it will fail if someone *other than you* has made changes that would be overwritten.